# angularjs get request is cancelled after switching to SSL

Tags: rest, angularjs, ssl

I have a couple of services that fetches data via my REST api from the backend. This all worked fine, until I enabled SSL on the server.

Now the the requests never reach the server, chrome network inspector indicates that those requests are "cancelled" and "pending"

**Note** The frontend is running on the same domain, and via ssl.

Just in case this is something to do with my server config, here it is:

```
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       ${buildout:directory}/parts/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  70;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name localhost;
        rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    server {
        server_name localhost;
        listen 443;
        access_log  ${logs:access_log};

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate ${buildout:directory}/dev/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key ${buildout:directory}/dev/server.key;

        location ^~ /media/ {
            root ${opts:media_dir};
            expires 31d;
        }

        location ^~ /static/ {
            root ${opts:media_dir};
            expires 31d;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://unix:${opts:socketfile}:;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_connect_timeout 10;
            proxy_read_timeout 10;

            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
            # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have CORS enabled?

Comment: no, but it's worked fine before so I didn't see why I should enable it just for ssl, when over plain http it worked. Also it's on the same domain, so cors shouldn't be required, no?

Comment: If you are requesting from http to https, they are different ports and even if they are the same domain CORS would be required.

Comment: I am requesting from https tho. Could it be something to do with my server config?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Turns out I had an extra nginx webserver running and I was restarting the wrong one every time I updated configuration. Killing the rogue nginx server and reloading the correct one fixed the problem.